# How can I add a column to calculate whether there is at least one record?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe 'df' like this:

```
   user_id  record
0        a      No
1        a      No
2        a     Yes
3        b      No
4        b      No
5        c     Yes
6        c     Yes
```

Each row means a record of a users operation. The column 'record' means whether the operation is illegal. Now I want to add a column to show whether a user has illegal operation. The result should be:

```
   user_id  record history
0        a      No       1
1        a      No       1
2        a     Yes       1
3        b      No       0
4        b      No       0
5        c     Yes       1
6        c     Yes       1
```

Once the user has at least 1 illegal operation, all the 'history' should be 1. How can I get this?

Comment: Yes/No, 0/1, why not use actual booleans?

Comment: I just give a simple example here. My question is much more complex. THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit faster than your solution:

```
df['history'] = df['record'].eq('Yes').groupby(df['user_id']).transform('any')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Btw, could you please share some docs about 'transform' and its frequently used parameters?

Comment: Do you mean this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)?

Comment: Thx. Is it the same as the 'transform' method of 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy' ? Since you used it after groupby.

Comment: exactly, because `df['record'].eq('Yes')` is a series.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried one way.

```
df['history'] = df.groupby('user_id').transform(lambda x: int('Yes' in x.values))
```

This can solve the problem. But I think it's not a smart idea.