# Fill a new column if within group a value is present in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
Groups subgroups Species Value 
G1     subg1     Sp1     NO 
G1     subg1     Sp1     YES 
G1     subg1     Sp2     NO 
G2     subg5     Sp7     YES
G2     subg6     Sp7     NO
G2     subg7     Sp7     NO 
G2     subg7     Sp7     YES 
G3     subg1     Sp1     NO 
G3     subg1     Sp1     NO
```

and I would like to fill a new `Value2` column where within each `Groups`, `subgroups` and `Species` with "YES" if there is at least one **YES** within this group, and **NO** is there is none.

I should then get :

```
Groups subgroups Species Value Value2
G1     subg1     Sp1     NO    YES
G1     subg1     Sp1     YES   YES
G1     subg1     Sp2     NO    NO
G2     subg5     Sp7     YES   YES
G2     subg6     Sp7     NO    NO
G2     subg7     Sp7     NO    YES
G2     subg7     Sp7     YES   YES
G3     subg1     Sp1     NO    NO
G3     subg1     Sp1     NO    NO
```

Comment: Gotta be a dup: `df.groupby(['Groups', 'subgroups', 'Species'])['Value'].transform('max')`

Comment: This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61242093/15497888) of yours is similar @QuangHoang There's also the standard [transform max](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35640364/15497888)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby`, `transform`:

```
df['Value2'] = (df['Value']=="YES").groupby([df['Groups'], 
                                             df['subgroups'], 
                                             df['Species']])\
                                   .transform('any')\
                                   .map({True:"YES", False:"NO"})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Groups subgroups Species Value Value2
0     G1     subg1     Sp1    NO    YES
1     G1     subg1     Sp1   YES    YES
2     G1     subg1     Sp2    NO     NO
3     G2     subg5     Sp7   YES    YES
4     G2     subg6     Sp7    NO     NO
5     G2     subg7     Sp7    NO    YES
6     G2     subg7     Sp7   YES    YES
7     G3     subg1     Sp1    NO     NO
8     G3     subg1     Sp1    NO     NO
```

Answer (score 1):

use np.where, groupby, transform

```
  df['Value2']=np.where(df.groupby(['Groups','subgroups','Species'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: (x=='YES').any()), 'YES','NO')

  Groups subgroups Species Value
0     G1     subg1     Sp1    NO
1     G1     subg1     Sp1   YES
2     G1     subg1     Sp2    NO
3     G2     subg5     Sp7   YES
4     G2     subg6     Sp7    NO
5     G2     subg7     Sp7    NO
6     G2     subg7     Sp7   YES
7     G3     subg1     Sp1    NO
8     G3     subg1     Sp1    NO
```